# How to decide whether I should throw ArgumentException or ArgumentNullException in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

As stated in my question I want to know that what is the logical difference between **Argument** and **ArgumentNull** exception in c# Exceptions.

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [Docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.argumentexception(v=vs.110).aspx):

> ArgumentException is thrown when a method is invoked and at least one
>   of the passed arguments does not meet the parameter specification of
>   the called method. The ParamName property identifies the invalid
>   argument.
>
> The primary derived classes of ArgumentException are
>   **ArgumentNullException** and **ArgumentOutOfRangeException**. These derived
>   classes should be used instead of **ArgumentException**, except in
>   situations where neither of the derived classes is acceptable. For
>   example, exceptions should be thrown by:
>
> - **ArgumentNullException** whenever null is passed to a method that does not accept it as a valid argument.
> - **ArgumentOutOfRangeException** when the value of an argument is outside the range of acceptable values; for example, when the value
>     "46" is passed as the month argument during the creation of a
>     DateTime.

In other words:

`ArgumentException` means at least one parameter specification is not valid. It doesn't mean that it is *NULL*, it can be any rule that is not satisfied. `ArgumentNullException` is just a special case when the rule is for the arguments not to be *NULL*

Comment: the answer I'm looking for. thx.